# How to unset a jquery tab cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

Hi i have the following code

```
 var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
      cookie: { expires:1 }
  });
```

this very nice. But how can i unset this cookie?
something like

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "cookie", { expires: 0 } );
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the name of the cookie in the parameters.

> *Since jQuery UI 1.7 it is also possible to define the cookie name being used via name property.*

Name your cookie this way :

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    cookie: { expires:1, name: "tab_cookie" }
});
```

Since jQuery uses jquery.plugin.cookie.js for this to work, you can use this same plugin to erase your cookie :

```
$.cookie('tab_cookie', null);
```

Comment: Almost, my cookie name has an underscore :p

Comment: Tnx for quick reactions it works!
But how can i set the cookie again in the tab after deletion?

Comment: The cookie will be set again when you'll chose another tab. Or you can set it yourself with `$.cookie('tab_cookie', 0);`, **0** being the first tab.

Comment: Okay, i have this method to set the cookie but it doesnt work

    `function setCookie() {
 var cookie = $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "cookie", { expires:1 } );
}`

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery UI tabs cookie option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cookie) has an additional name parameter which lets you specifically define the name of the cookie, as opposed to letting jQuery UI define the name.  If you do this, then you can control the cookie with the [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) to delete it.

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
     cookie: { expires:1, name: "tabcookie" }
});
$.cookie('tabcookie', null);
```